# I have an old Shepherd's lantern made of tin and painted glass. How can I polish/shine the tin?

Tags: cleaning

The lantern is soldered together with lead so I don't believe that can be shined/polished. The tin is my concern and if neither can even be polished I suppose a metal paint can be applied but that's expensive and a last resort.

It is made to hang on a hook and carry a large candle within. The door latches shut. It's a very nice display and usable piece that I'd love to beautify.

Comment: Strangely, a toothbrush and toothpaste could polish it, even over solder, if done carefully. That said, it's value as an an antique would be reduced by polishing.